# py.test does not correctly import modules from conftest - fails with ConftestImportFailure: ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, pytest

`pytest` fails to import modules even though these modules import fine under the vanilla `python` interpreter. Especially modules imported from `conftest` fails to resolve. ImportErrori is raised when pytest tries to rewrite assert information in modules.

An example traceback:

```
================================================================================================================================================ test session starts ================================================================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.2, pytest-3.8.1, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.7.1 -- /yyy/venv/bin/python3.6
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /yyy/corporategovernance, inifile: setup.cfg
plugins: timeout-1.3.1, cov-2.5.1, populus-1.9.0, flaky-3.4.0, celery-4.1.0, splinter-1.8.5+headless
collecting 0 items / 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
====================================================================================================================================================== ERRORS =======================================================================================================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting corporategovernance/__init__.py __________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:381: in _getconftestmodules
    return self._path2confmods[path]
E   KeyError: local('/xxx/tests')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:412: in _importconftest
    return self._conftestpath2mod[conftestpath]
E   KeyError: local('/xxx/tests/conftest.py')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:418: in _importconftest
    mod = conftestpath.pyimport()
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:668: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:290: in load_module
    six.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
corporategovernance/tests/conftest.py:4: in <module>
    import corporategovernance.backend
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corporategovernance.backend'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py:201: in __init__
    self.result = func()
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py:261: in <lambda>
    call = CallInfo(lambda: list(collector.collect()), "collect")
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:624: in collect
    for x in self._collectfile(path):
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:579: in _collectfile
    ihook = self.gethookproxy(path)
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/python.py:568: in gethookproxy
    my_conftestmodules = pm._getconftestmodules(fspath)
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:395: in _getconftestmodules
    mod = self._importconftest(conftestpath)
../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py:431: in _importconftest
    raise ConftestImportFailure(conftestpath, sys.exc_info())
E   _pytest.config.ConftestImportFailure: ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'corporategovernance.backend'",)
E     File "/yyy/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 290, in load_module
E       six.exec_(co, mod.__dict__)
E     File "/xxx/tests/conftest.py", line 4, in <module>
E       import corporategovernance.backend
===Flaky Test Report===
```

How to resolve?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

pytest may be picky if you have `__init__.py` files under your `tests` folder and subfolders. This may cause pytest to resolve Python modules in incorrect order under certain circumstances.

The workaround is to remove all `__init__.py` files under tests.

Comment: I actually added an empty `__init__.py` in `app/tests/` and it worked. `platform linux -- Python 3.7.3, pytest-4.4.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0 -- /home/roy/trainer/venv/bin/python3.7`