# import file mismatch in pytest

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-cov

I've got a file in the package with 'test' in its name and when I run pytest I got an error

```
import file mismatch:
imported module 'my_project.my_file_test' has this __file__ attribute:
  /my_project/src/my_project/build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo/my_file_test.py
which is not the same as the test file we want to collect:
  /my_project/src/my_project/build/private/python2.7/lib/foo/my_file_test.py
HINT: remove __pycache__ / .pyc files and/or use a unique basename for your test file modules
```

If I remove 'test' from the file it works fine but unfortunately I can't change it.

So the question is how to tell pytest to ignore this file?

Comment: Did you try to remove the `__pycache__` dirs?

Comment: Yes. That was the first I did - remove *.pyc and __pycache__ but it didn’t help

Comment: renaming the file in question fixed it for me. Tried deleting the pycache, creating the init file but nothing fixed it.

Comment: In my case is that I was using the same name for a module in my project directory tree. Is tricky to understand the error if the project is extensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So finally it was easy, I just had to add test file pattern to the `pytest.ini` file:

```
python_files = test_*.py
```

so pytest stopped looking for files with `test` in the end of the name what it did by default.

Comment: Might help someone. I had two test fiiles with the same name, renaming one resolved my issue.

Comment: @Francois thanks, that saved me some time, it blows my mind how awful that is though

Answer (score 79):

In my case, it was missing `__init__.py` file in tests directory.

Comment: Adding an `__init__.py` works like a charm. Hopefully they add it to the hint.

Comment: [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52589913/56541) suggests _removing_ `__init__.py` from the tests directory...

Comment: Worked for me by removing __init__.py . Weird.

Comment: Hello @Mateusz, why do you need an `__init__.py` file inside your `test/` directory?, can you share with us some reference about it?

Answer (score 7):

A working solution from [Pytest Issues 3151](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/3151)

Exact Quotes of the solver below:

> This is happening because your test files have the same name in two
> different directories, and they are imported into the global namespace
> because there's no `init files; there's a more detailed explanation in
> the docs.
>
> In this case you can either create `case/__init__.py` and
> `pytest/__init__.py` files or rename the test files to unique names.

Apart from this, if possible try changing the names of your testcases file.

Answer (score 6):

As pytest explains:

> *For historical reasons, pytest defaults to the prepend import mode instead of the importlib import mode we recommend for new projects. The reason lies in the way the prepend mode works.*

See https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#choosing-an-import-mode
and https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/pythonpath.html#import-modes

Basically it means, when using old `prepend`(default) tests are imported as packages, and therefore you need `__init__.py` files inside test folders.

Solution defined by pytest at the mentioned links:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
addopts = "--import-mode=importlib"
```

With this, `importlib` is used to collect tests and therefore `__ini__.py` files are not longer needed and test files can share names (always that are located in different folders).

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue even though my file name was not exactly same as other.

I had `test_01_login_chrome.py` and `test_01_login_firefox.py`

Error I was getting

```
import file mismatch:
imported module 'test_01_login_chrome.py' has this __file__ attribute:
  /Users/avicii/PycharmProjects/Omni_Sanity/TestCase/Firefox_TestCases/test_01_login_chrome.py
which is not the same as the test file we want to collect:
  /Users/avicii/PycharmProjects/Omni_Sanity/TestCase/01_Chrome_TestCases/test_01_login_chrome.py
HINT: remove __pycache__ / .pyc files and/or use a unique basename for your test file modules
```

I tried adding `__init__.py` to the test cases folder and it did not work.

Then I tried a workaround. I created a python package for my test cases, which created `__init__.py` by default and then moved my test cases to that folder.

And my issue was resolved.

Comment: incomprehensible. Please describe better

Answer (score 0):

A small variation of this case using the `_pytester_` plugin included with `_pytest_` (that yields the same error.)

There is a feature of the plugin that allows placement of example tests in your project root (outside of the package), and those tests can be copied into a test temp directory via `_pytester.copy_example()_`.

This feature can be used as a test loader, and also as a way to test examples.

If you use this feature, you will also want to put an `\_\_init\_\_.py` into the source directory for your examples.

E.g.: if copying the example from the *examples* directory:

```py
pytester.copy_example("examples/test_zfs.py")
```

To avoid the import file mismatch error:

```bash
$ touch examples/__init__.py
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the error because I was missing `__init__.py` file not in tests directory but the one above it.

Comment: this answer is not novel. It is the same as what has already been answered above.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34301160)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using tests directory in each app and I forgot to remove `tests.py` file that is already created by default in Django. When I removed the `tests.py` file, everything worked fine.